# Automatic Scrolling through variable size elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scroll

I am creating a teaching web app of sort where each step in the lesson is an

within a . I do not want to display all steps of the lesson at once and so I am currently using overflow hidden to only show a few within the current view. How do I go about scrolling between elements automatically if each

is of variable height based on the length of that step within the lesson. Essentially is there a way to smoothly automatic scroll using the window not based on a fixed increment but instead based on the width of the next DOM element within the ?

Comment: Are you trying to vertical or horizontal scroll of each step of the lesson? If it is a vertical scroll, maybe you can take a look at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/uoV00amE28FtWAoA161a?p=preview

Comment: Assuming you meant height and not width within your second bullet point: you may be able to use anchors with id: `<a id="QUESTION_1_ANS"></a>`. Then changing the windows hash will scroll the location of the QUESTION_1_ANS tag to the top of the window: `location.hash = '#QUESTION_1_ANS';`